# Free compression library for C# which supports 7zip (LZMA)

Tags: c#, compression, 7zip, lzma

I have a program (written in C#) that reads/writes its data directly (direct file access without server) to firebird database files. For a better exchange I want to (un)compress them on import/export for a better exchange over the internet without the need of an external program to (un)compress them.

I know [#ziplib](http://www.sharpdevelop.com/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx) which supports Zip, GZip, Tar and BZip2.

What else free compression libraries for C# do you know?
Is there a .NET library which supports LZMA so i can read/write ".7z" files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a good article written by Peter Bromberg:

[7Zip (LZMA) In-Memory Compression with C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20081207080706/http://www.eggheadcafe.com:80/tutorials/aspnet/064b41e4-60bc-4d35-9136-368603bcc27a/7zip-lzma-inmemory-com.aspx)

> Shows a simple C#
>   `SevenZip.Compression.Lzma.SevenZipHelper`
>   class to enable high-compression of
>   in-memory objects with C#. Adds a new
>   7Zip format LZMA Cookie Compression
>   class to the previously published
>   CookieCompression utility.

Comment: @Kissaki external links are okay for certain situations; including: 1)The amount of relevant external material is huge, for example a specification. 2) Links which are supporting information only 3) material which can't be copy-pasted due to copyrights

Comment: I'm not sure why that specific web.archive.org URL was used in this answer but the source URL is http://www.nullskull.com/a/768/7zip-lzma-inmemory-compression-with-c.aspx.  Also, some helpful information with examples can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8605828/1039753.

Comment: Keep in mind, Peter Bromberg's SevenZipHelper default class is extremely slow with the default properties.
3600 (6c/12t) vs 144Mb sql file:

`default settings: 135 sec! -> 7.9Mb` vs `without properties (//encoder.SetCoderProperties): 34 sec -> 8.2Mb` vs `using 7zr.exe: 9 sec!!! 8.2Mb`

Imo the programatical settings are not using all threads, only two of them, vs 7zr.exe which used at least 6 threads.

Answer (score 26):

7-zip has a free source code, public domain C# SDK for the LZMA algorithm:

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that it's free source code, public domain, and in C# :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You ar right. Added this information.

Comment: Some other helpful examples on how to use it can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8605828/1039753.

Answer (score 8):

You may try [SevenZipSharp](http://www.codeplex.com/sevenzipsharp)

Comment: It's under LGPL v3.0 if anyone need the license.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be quite a little known fact but .NET library includes [packaging/compression API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx)

Comment: Here is an example using that API:
http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2012/zip-files-using-c-net-without-any-extra-libraries/

Comment: Is this MS specific? Nowaways I would not like to use a MS-only solution anymore. I mean if I pack a file, I would expect it to be used on non-MS-machines as well.

Comment: @JensB that link is now dead.

Comment: @ArvoBowen Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis

Comment: @JensB great question to look at but I don't think that has anything to do with `7zip` (and that's why I came to see this question.  I ended up getting the 7zip SDK from https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html and read up on the article found at http://www.nullskull.com/a/768/7zip-lzma-inmemory-compression-with-c.aspx.  I was able to use that guys `SevenZipHelper.cs` file with the SDK from 7-zip.org and got it to work.

Comment: It has to do with the suggested answer. How to do it natively in C#. With no libraries, which is exactly what the dead link showed once upon a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing individual files, then you could just treat it as a stream and use the inbuilt [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) / [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) (although in some tests I did, #ZipLib out-performed the MS offering for both ratio and speed). Or there is inbuilt zip support somewhere in the framework. I don't know about LZMA, though.

Comment: Beware: GZipStream has a size limitation of 4Gb

Comment: please refere to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505190/net-deflatestream-4gb-limit