# Is it necessary to use multiple gzip members for input larger than 4GB?

Tags: compression, gzip, deflate

By [stating](https://code.google.com/p/idzip/#Acknowledgement)

> Features:
>
> - no 4GB limit
>
> ...
>
> Idzip just uses multiple gzip members to have no file size limit.

[the author of idzip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010096/709537) seems to imply that multiple gzip members are necessary to support data > 4GB.

But the [deflate algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951), whose output gzip members merely wrap with header and footer, [evidently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505887/709537) supports more than 4GB of input.

So is it really necessary to use multiple gzip members to compress more than 4GB of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even .net's `GZipStream`, which does not support multiple members (contrary to the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-5) btw), nevertheless supports gzip files with more 4GB, now that ([since .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505887/709537)) the underlying `DeflateStream` supports it.

So that would seal it: **Multiple gzip members are NOT necessary for input greater than 4GB.**

The [gzip specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-5) do not constrain the size either:

```
  Each member has the following structure:

     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     |ID1|ID2|CM |FLG|     MTIME     |XFL|OS | (more-->)
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

... [omitting optional headers]

     +=======================+
     |...compressed blocks...| (more-->)
     +=======================+

       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     |     CRC32     |     ISIZE     |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

     ISIZE (Input SIZE)
        This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input
        data modulo 2^32.
```

The important part here is

> size of original (uncompressed) input data **modulo 2^32**.