# Alternatives to SharpZipLib for use with .Net C# application

Tags: c#, zip, licensing

Does anyone have recommendations for an alternative library to SharpZipLib for full featured ZIP file handling using C#?

The reason we're looking for an alternative is the **licensing**.  Despite the added clause to that projects GPL license, it still doesn't fly with our legal requirements. Most other open source licenses will do, especially academic or BSD-esque.  Commercial licenses are also cool.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what licensing problems did you run into? As far as I was aware, the added clause basically means you can use SharpZipLib for anything without worrying about copyleft, as long as you provide the GPL license text and a copy (or link) to the source.

Comment: Short answer is that we had the lawyers look at it.  There is a lot in the GPL that's prohibitive to our usage of it, and it doesn't get addressed with that single clause.  There are very specific issues with GPL and distribution of source code, openness of the build process, due-process that has been established.  If it allowed re-licensing .. that'd be a different story. :)

Comment: For those who may come across this in the future, SharpZipLib is now licensed under the MIT License.  https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib

Answer (score 13):

Hey all, thanks for the tips. I ended up finding one alternative in (the obviously named): [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

It's licensed under the MSPL, which is on our OK'ed license list.  Will report back on success.

Comment: +1. Love this library.  Started using it recently and it's been way easier to use than SharpZipLib.  And, as you mentioned, the licensing is a plus.

Comment: @dariusz, what's the feedback?

Answer (score 3):

A related question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis) which may give you what you need, although the answer focuses only on zipping using the framework itself (.Net3.5)

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [zip alternatives](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=733)

Comment: It's worth nothing that this article is from 2003 and 10 years old as of this comment. There's probably a more current article on the subject.

Comment: link is not working anymore