# zip more than 1 file in GzipStream

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

How can I zip more than 1 file in a GZipStream? I have 3 xml files and I want to zip them into one .gz file and when I decompress I should get all 3 separate files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

gzip is only designed to hold a single file. You will need to collate them in some other container before gzipping them.

Comment: i did'nt get collate them in some other container... please throw some more light on this Abram

Comment: He's saying the same thing as Matthew - you'll need to combine the three files into one file *before* you compress.

Comment: First you pick a container, like, say, JSON. Then you create a JSON string containing the three files. And then you compress the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You can [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) them together first.  [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) has support for tar, as well as its own GZip implementation.  See the SharpZipLib.Tar namespace.  The docs are [here](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/DownloadLatestVersion.asp?what=Help).

Comment: is it a microsoft library or 3rd party?? coz my client does not accept third parties...

Comment: It's third-party class.  That seems like a rather arbitrary requirement.

Comment: You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis).  But note that ZipPackage isn't a general-purpose Zip class.