# Upload multiple files to webserver using GzipStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzipstream

I know how to upload single file to web server but my requirement is to upload multiple files to web server.
I want to compress all the files and then want to upload the zip file to webserver.Now I have problem that how I can zip multiple files using **GzipStream**

Comment: down voter please provide explation

Comment: Gzipstream is not designed to handle multiple files, even though it should be possible somehow. Why don't you try a library which can handle more files? E.g. DotNetZip

Comment: Here you can find the [GzipStream](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream) example and after then you need to make a thread which will read your whole directory in which you are placing those uploaded files and then zip them one by one.

Comment: Thanks Janes and freak

Comment: @muski dont worry about those downvoters who didn't comment.They are just fulfilling their habit

Comment: @freak:you are absolutely right.I don't have privilege to vote a comment so that I can't give you vote.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih DOtNetZip is support for Framweork2.0. is there any alternative for Framweork2.0??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GzipStream can allow only one file to zip and is only designed to hold a single file.Here you can find the [GzipStream](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream) example and after then you need to make a thread which will read your whole directory in which you are placing those uploaded files and then zip them one by one.
Here in a [question of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042281/zip-more-than-1-file-in-gzipstream) and [on msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a4de19b3-df49-44b7-a1d4-d2123788493b) you can get a guess that how to compress multiple files using gzipstream.
 Also [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) also provide you very flexibility to zip multiple files