# Need help in Zipping files to local machine

Tags: c#, winforms, zip, c#-2.0

Okay here it goes, I want to Zip up files from several IP's, to my local machine. This for a development tool that I am creating, this tools so far can upload files from My local machine to 20 IP's, now this functionality is new and is the other way around and I want to know a way of zipping up files and saving on my machine.
Any documents, articles, resources and code snippets to show how to go about it can be helpful. I am still using .Net 2.0 and No third part lib...

Thanks,
HRG

Comment: If you are using .NET 3.5 you can use built-in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis

Comment: @Sascha: I am still using .Net 2.0 :( I have heard about ZipPackage, K will edit this info in my question. Thanks

Comment: .NET has a built-in feature to zip files.  You should use that.

Answer (score 2):

Please look here : http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Or if you can use .NET 4.5 RC you have Zip functionality included.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure if I can use External Lib's:(

Comment: Ok so this is Open Source code, will check this out, this was pointed out by Felice... Thanks again.

Comment: Felice and me we are proposing the same library. Don't forget to upvote and or mark the question as answered!

Comment: @JasonDeOliveira I noticed just now my post is a duplicate, so i removed it and +1 your