# LZMA compression in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, compression, lzma

I have used NSIS to create installers before and I love the LZMA compression it supports.

Now I'm learning VS and was wondering if we can compress files using LZMA or any other way?

I'm primarily using C# and Windows Forms.

Comment: Possibly already answered by this SO question: [Free compression library for C# which supports 7zip (LZMA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449998/free-compression-library-for-c-which-supports-7zip-lzma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7zip offers a public domain library with C# source for LZMA compression - see http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html