# c# looking for API to read 7z headers

Tags: c#, crc, 7zip, dotnetzip

Is there c# based API for 7zip (7z) that supports the ability to read its header to retrieve the CRC information for each file in the compressed archive?  Everything I have looked at requires you to decompress the file. I am writing an application that compares the CRCs of the files in a compressed folder with a separate list.

I currently am using DotNetZip for zip files and it works great. Unfortunately it has no .7z support.

EDIT: Exception generated when calling ZipFile.Read()

```
{Ionic.Zip.ZipException: Cannot read that as a ZipFile ---> Ionic.Zip.BadReadException:   Bad signature (0xAFBC7A37) at position  0x00000000
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.ReadHeader(ZipEntry ze, Encoding defaultEncoding)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.ReadEntry(ZipContainer zc, Boolean first)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadIntoInstance_Orig(ZipFile zf)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadIntoInstance(ZipFile zf)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadIntoInstance(ZipFile zf)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(String fileName, TextWriter statusMessageWriter, Encoding encoding, EventHandler`1 readProgress)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(String fileName)
```

...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free compression library for C# which supports 7zip (LZMA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449998/free-compression-library-for-c-sharp-which-supports-7zip-lzma)

Comment: Not really. Unfortunately there is no easy way to read the CRC information from the headers with that API.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a duplicate post.. here look at some of the answers on this StackOverFlow Link
[Reading 7z files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net)

This should work for you if you are using DotNetZip try this example below

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
  foreach (ZipEntry ze in zip)
  {
    if (header)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Zipfile: {0}", zip.Name);
      if ((zip.Comment != null) && (zip.Comment != "")) 
        System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", zip.Comment);
      System.Console.WriteLine("\n{1,-22} {2,8}  {3,5}   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",
                               "Filename", "Modified", "Size", "Ratio", "Packed", "pw?");
      System.Console.WriteLine(new System.String('-', 72));
      header = false;
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("{1,-22} {2,8} {3,5:F0}%   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",
                             ze.FileName,
                             ze.LastModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                             ze.UncompressedSize,
                             ze.CompressionRatio,
                             ze.CompressedSize,
                             (ze.UsesEncryption) ? "Y" : "N");

  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen that post already. Unfortunately none of those APIs *seem* to have calls to read the CRCs for each file in the compressed archive.

Comment: I was looking more into 7ZipStream
http://code.google.com/p/7zipstream/source/browse/trunk/_Documentation/7zC.txt?r=3

In step 5 of "Steps for using 7z decoder" I came the list items example. I wonder if there is something in CFileItem.

Comment: if you are using DotNetZip I am going to post something that may work for you.. let me know if this is something that could possibly work

Comment: I thought DotNetZip does not support 7z files? I am using the ZipEntry API already for the .zip files though.

Comment: I found an example that looks like DotnetZip would work..I don't have it installed on my local but at work machine I do.. so can't test it just give it a try.. step thru the code and see if it's what you are looking for or if the code snippet helps

Comment: I end up getting an exception "Cannot read that as a ZipFile". This is  what lead me to believe DotNetZip did not support 7z.

Comment: I should mention that that exception is generated during ZipFile.Read() call

Comment: Pasted my detailed exception above in my first post

Comment: Hi,
I'm facing the same problem , did you find a solution to extract this files?